# convert textView to double

Tags: java, android, textview, double

in my app I get a textView and I need to convert it to a double to be able to perform some calculations,
what i'm trying to do is this:

```
String ResultN = resultadoN.getText().toString();
double RN = Double.parseDouble(ResultN);
```

on android studio it runs, but on the smartphone when I add values ​​it breaks

Comment: Hi Gustavo! I think you need to complete your question, at least showing the code where are you adding values and if it is breaking and you have the stack trace you could put it here as well. From the information that you put it here it is hard to understand your situation

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(str)` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the provided string is not a valid double. This includes blank strings, things like `1..1` or `1.2.3.2`, or words or phrases that aren't numbers. In general you should put it in a try-catch to handle those cases or your app will crash. You should also be aware of locale-specific issues like the difference between `1.23` and `1,23` when parsing user input.

Answer (score 0):

double RN ;
try {
RN = RN. parse RN (Result N. get Text().to String().replace All("S\$|\.$", ""));
}
catch (Number Format Exception e) {

```
Result N. set Error("Please enter a valid number");
```

}

Comment: Please reformat your post, e. g. surround code with triple backticks.